# C# error message: This document already has a 'DocumentElement' node

Tags: c#, xml

First of all, thank you for your previous help,
Now I came to a problem that I really can't see. I'm getting the error message "This document already has a 'DocumentElement' node".

I've created the XML file that contains a set of data. Now I need to append additional data to it and an error message is as above.

The code I have for now (short snippet where I think that error message is):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(@"C:\Test\Test.xml");
        
        using (XmlWriter writer = doc.CreateNavigator().AppendChild())
        {
            
            Dictionary<string, List<int>> idNums = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();

            foreach (var row in gkRadnici.Rows.Cast<System.Data.DataRow>().ToArray())
            {
                writer.WriteStartElement("Obrazac1022");
                writer.WriteStartElement("Dio1PodaciOPoslodavcuIPoreznomObvezniku");
                writer.WriteElementString("JIBJMBPoslodavca", this.label7.Text);
                writer.WriteElementString("Naziv", this.label9.Text);
                writer.WriteElementString("AdresaSjedista", this.label11.Text);
                string Item1 = row["JMBG"].ToString();
                string Item2 = row["ImePrezime"].ToString();
                string adresa = row["Adresa"].ToString();
                writer.WriteElementString("JMBZaposlenika", Item1);
                writer.WriteElementString("ImeIPrezime", Item2);
                writer.WriteElementString("AdresaPrebivalista", adresa);
                writer.WriteElementString("PoreznaGodina", txtPoslovnaGodina.Text);
                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.WriteStartElement("Dio2PodaciOPrihodimaDoprinosimaIPorezu");
                for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
                {


                    string Item0 = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[Pozicija0].Text;
                    string Item3 = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[Pozicija3].Text;
                    string Item4 = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[Pozicija4].Text;
                    string Item5 = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[Pozicija5].Text;
                    string Item6 = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[Pozicija6].Text;
                    string Item8 = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[Pozicija8].Text;
                    string Item9 = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[Pozicija9].Text;
                    string Item10 = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[Pozicija10].Text;
                    string Item11 = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[Pozicija11].Text;
                    string Item12 = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[Pozicija12].Text;
                    string Item13 = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[Pozicija13].Text;
                    string Item14 = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[Pozicija14].Text;
                    string Item15 = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[Pozicija15].Text;
                    string Item16 = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[Pozicija16].Text;
                    string Item17 = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[Pozicija17].Text;
                    double a, z, l, a1, a2, a3, a4;
                    string IznosNovca;
                    a1 = Convert.ToDouble(Item8);
                    a2 = Convert.ToDouble(Item9);
                    a3 = Convert.ToDouble(Item10);
                    a4 = a1 + a2 + a3;
                    string placa;
                    String doprinosi;
                    a = Convert.ToDouble(Item5);
                    z = Convert.ToDouble(Item11);
                    l = a - a4;
                    placa = Convert.ToString(l.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                    doprinosi = Convert.ToString(a4.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                    DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(Item17);
                    string aa = Convert.ToString(date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));

                    decimal d3 = decimal.Parse(Item5);
                    string bplaca = Convert.ToString(d3.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                    decimal d4 = decimal.Parse(Item6);
                    string BSU = Convert.ToString(d4.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                    decimal d5 = d3 + d4;
                    string Brutozbir = Convert.ToString(d5.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                    decimal d6 = decimal.Parse(Item8);
                    string PIO = Convert.ToString(d6.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                    decimal d7 = decimal.Parse(Item9);
                    string ZZO = Convert.ToString(d7.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                    decimal d8 = decimal.Parse(Item10);
                    string OON = Convert.ToString(d8.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                    decimal d9 = d6 + d7 + d8;
                    string UDoprisnos = Convert.ToString(d9.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                    decimal d10 = d5 - d9;
                    string PBDopr = Convert.ToString(d10.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                    decimal d11 = decimal.Parse(Item12);
                    string Flic = Convert.ToString(d11.ToString("0.000", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                    decimal d12 = decimal.Parse(Item13);
                    string IznsoLO = Convert.ToString(d12.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                    decimal d13 = decimal.Parse(Item14);
                    string OsnovicaP = Convert.ToString(d13.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                    decimal d14 = decimal.Parse(Item15);
                    string IznosPO = Convert.ToString(d14.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                    decimal d15 = decimal.Parse(Item16);
                    string NetoP = Convert.ToString(d15.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));




                    writer.WriteStartElement("PodaciOPrihodimaDoprinosimaIPorezu");
                    writer.WriteElementString("Mjesec", Item0);
                    writer.WriteElementString("IsplataZaMjesecIGodinu", Item3);
                    writer.WriteElementString("VrstaIsplate", Item4);
                    writer.WriteElementString("IznosPrihodaUNovcu", bplaca);
                    writer.WriteElementString("IznosPrihodaUStvarimaUslugama", BSU);
                    writer.WriteElementString("BrutoPlaca", Brutozbir);
                    writer.WriteElementString("IznosZaPenzijskoInvalidskoOsiguranje", PIO);
                    writer.WriteElementString("IznosZaZdravstvenoOsiguranje", ZZO);
                    writer.WriteElementString("IznosZaOsiguranjeOdNezaposlenosti", OON);
                    writer.WriteElementString("UkupniDoprinosi", UDoprisnos);
                    writer.WriteElementString("PlacaBezDoprinosa", PBDopr);
                    writer.WriteElementString("FaktorLicnihOdbitakaPremaPoreznojKartici", Flic);
                    writer.WriteElementString("IznosLicnogOdbitka", IznsoLO);
                    writer.WriteElementString("OsnovicaPoreza", OsnovicaP);
                    writer.WriteElementString("IznosUplacenogPoreza", IznosPO);
                    writer.WriteElementString("NetoPlaca", NetoP);
                    writer.WriteElementString("DatumUplate", aa);
                    writer.WriteEndElement();


                }
                double valorSum = 0;
                double sum1 = 0;
                double sum2 = 0;
                double sum3 = 0;
                double sum4 = 0;
                double sum5 = 0;
                double sum6 = 0;
                double sum7 = 0;
                double sum8 = 0;

                foreach (ListViewItem lstItem in listView1.Items)
                {
                    valorSum += double.Parse(lstItem.SubItems[5].Text);
                    sum1 += double.Parse(lstItem.SubItems[6].Text);
                    sum2 += double.Parse(lstItem.SubItems[8].Text);
                    sum3 += double.Parse(lstItem.SubItems[9].Text);
                    sum4 += double.Parse(lstItem.SubItems[10].Text);
                    sum5 += double.Parse(lstItem.SubItems[13].Text);
                    sum6 += double.Parse(lstItem.SubItems[14].Text);
                    sum7 += double.Parse(lstItem.SubItems[15].Text);
                    sum8 += double.Parse(lstItem.SubItems[16].Text);
                }
                string nz = Convert.ToString(valorSum.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                string bus = Convert.ToString(sum1.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                double g;
                g = valorSum + sum1;
                string platabruto = Convert.ToString(g.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                string pioukupno = Convert.ToString(sum2.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                string zzoukupno = Convert.ToString(sum3.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                string oonukupno = Convert.ToString(sum4.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                double b;
                b = sum2 + sum3 + sum4;
                string uudop = Convert.ToString(b.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                double c;
                c = g - b;
                string bezdop = Convert.ToString(c.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                string sumLO = Convert.ToString(sum5.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                string sumPO = Convert.ToString(sum6.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                string sumUP = Convert.ToString(sum7.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                string sumNP = Convert.ToString(sum8.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));

                writer.WriteStartElement("Ukupno");
                writer.WriteElementString("IznosPrihodaUNovcu", nz);
                writer.WriteElementString("IznosPrihodaUStvarimaUslugama", bus);
                writer.WriteElementString("BrutoPlaca", platabruto);
                writer.WriteElementString("IznosZaPenzijskoInvalidskoOsiguranje", pioukupno);
                writer.WriteElementString("IznosZaZdravstvenoOsiguranje", zzoukupno);
                writer.WriteElementString("IznosZaOsiguranjeOdNezaposlenosti", oonukupno);
                writer.WriteElementString("UkupniDoprinosi", uudop);
                writer.WriteElementString("PlacaBezDoprinosa", bezdop);
                writer.WriteElementString("IznosLicnogOdbitka", sumLO);
                writer.WriteElementString("OsnovicaPoreza", sumPO);
                writer.WriteElementString("IznosUplacenogPoreza", sumUP);
                writer.WriteElementString("NetoPlaca", sumNP);
                writer.WriteEndElement();


                writer.WriteEndElement();

                writer.WriteStartElement("Dio3IzjavaPoslodavcaIsplatioca");
                writer.WriteElementString("JIBJMBPoslodavca", this.label7.Text);
                writer.WriteElementString("DatumUnosa", this.dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
                writer.WriteElementString("NazivPoslodavca", this.label9.Text);
                writer.WriteEndElement();

                writer.WriteStartElement("Dokument");
                writer.WriteElementString("Operacija", "Novi");
                writer.WriteEndElement();

                writer.WriteEndElement();

            }                
            writer.WriteEndDocument();
            
            MessageBox.Show("XML fajl uspješno generisan.", "ABC PLATE 2021", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            
        }
```

I understand that code is a lot to read and I do apologize for this.

New data should append to the root of XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PaketniUvozObrazaca xmlns="urn:PaketniUvozObrazaca_V1_0.xsd">
  <PodaciOPoslodavcu>
    <JIBPoslodavca>4209862630000</JIBPoslodavca>
    <NazivPoslodavca>PZU APOTEKE LA VITA</NazivPoslodavca>
    <BrojZahtjeva>11</BrojZahtjeva>
    <DatumPodnosenja>2021-12-23</DatumPodnosenja>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you can simplify the code in your question by omitting all the `writer.WriteElementString` calls and obvious pairs of WriteStartElement/EndElement calls

Comment: You are trying to add a chlid to the document instead of adding to the root of the document with 'doc.CreateNavigator().AppendChild()'.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.createnavigator?view=net-6.0